# Freemarker - Only output xml tag if value is not empty

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I am producing what has the potential to be a very large XML using freemarker - replacing placeholders `${placeholder}` with values from a List i am maintaining.

I know that it is possible on a per xml tag basis to do the following

```
<placeholder>${placeholder}</placeholder>
```

This is an ok solution but seems excessive to have to do this for every tag.

Is there a better way to do this for all values pertaining to the one document?

Thanks

Comment: http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for the reply, I don't see how in that example you can ommit the tag completley if it contains no text

Comment: In your example there is no other elements inside `if` besides placeholder. So setting a default to empty string gives you pretty much the same result.

Comment: @AleksandrM so are you saying for me to not output the whole of the `<placeholder>` tag i need to wrap that in the if rather than the contents?

Comment: If i wrap the contents the it does ommit the tag but i would have to do that individually for ever tag?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to wrap the `<placeholder>${placeholder}</placeholder>` in an if statement and check if it was empty